# How to connect a wired internet connection through terminal?

Tags: command-line, internet, lan, wired

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with KDE on it.

I am facing a problem in connecting to a wired LAN internet connection.

I want to connect to wired internet connection with static IP and authentication.

How can I manage this via terminal?

Answer (score 24):

How to configure the network interface using the terminal

You can configure a network interface from the command line using the networking utilities. You configure your network client hosts with the command line by using commands to change your current settings or by editing a number of system files. To configure your network interface card to automatically connect when wired cable is connected you can follow this "simple" steps:

1. Configuring DHCP address for your network card

To configure DHCP address, edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` and enter the following lines replacing `eth0` in the example with your network interface card:

```
`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

You should see something similar to this:

    auto eth0  
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

in my computer it looks like this:

    auto lo  
    iface lo inet loopback
```

So if your network card appears as `eth2` for example then you would leave the file like this:

```
    auto eth2  
    iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

2. Just in case you want to configure a static IP address for your network card

Same procedure as above but you would need to include more information.

Like above, replace `eth0` with your networks card name:

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Example File:

```
    auto eth0  
    iface eth0 inet static  
    address 192.168.0.100  
    gateway 192.168.0.1  
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    network 192.168.0.0  
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

After entering all the details which are needed for your static IP you would need to restart networking services using the following command:

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

3. Setting up DNS

You can add hostname and/or IP addresses to the file `/etc/hosts` for static lookups.

To cause your machine to consult with a particular server for name lookups you simply add their addresses to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

For example a machine which should perform lookups from the DNS server at IP address 192.168.0.1 would have a `resolv.conf` file looking like this:

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

```
    search test.com  
    nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

in my case it looks like this:

```
    search cantv.net 
    nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: That's the fourth time I've visited this answer to solve this same problem. I'm putting `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` into a shell script and giving you an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

most answers on this issue are most likely to confuse readers when demostrating what to put in the `/etc/resolv.conf` because they use local addresses for the nameserver.

"For example a machine which should perform lookups from the **DNS server**."

Here DNS server and nameserver mean the same thing. So instead of placing a LAN address in there, put an actual DNS server address. (ie. Google DNS server)

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

this link explains the used of the resolv.conf file in more depth.
https://theos.in/desktop-linux/resolve-conf-linux-example/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what worked is:

```bsh
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
ping -c 5 www.google.com
```

If it does not work, run:

```bsh
ip link set enpxxx down
ip link set enpxxx up
dhclient enpxxx
```

`ping` should work now.

```bsh
ping -c 5 www.google.com
```

I found this solution on this page of the [ubuntu (french) wiki](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/recovery_mode#dpkgreparer_les_paquets_brises)

Answer (score 0):

With nmcli is dead easy

```
nmcli connection show
```

Then use the device name to connect

```
nmcli connection up uuid <device UUID>
```

Comment: I can see available connections, but can connect to selected one. `Error: Connection activation failed:No suitable device found for this connection`