# My TV cannot connect to Media Server Service on Windows7 (DNLA)

Tags: 12.04, network-bridge, dlna

Thanks to this article
[Sharing Connection to other PCs (Via Wired Ethernet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169473/sharing-connection-to-other-pcs-via-wired-ethernet) I am able to connect my TV to the internet. But my TV is not able to connect to WMS Windows Media Server running on other PC's in my home network. I would suspect that a 'normal' bridge simply forward packages. But it looks like my TV, connected through a laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, can not see the media server service on my Windows7 dekstop. Has anyone suggestions how to check the settings, or even how to make the connection work?
Thanks to the comments, the problem seems to be that my TV is on another subnet than my laptop and DLNA-server. How can I configure my settings on the laptop, so my TV gets on the same subnet?

Comment: Your TV may be on a different subnet as compared with your Windows 7 DNLA server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am sorry, but my knowledge of networking is very poor. Should I look at the Subnetmask/Netmask? It looks like it iś all on 255.255.255.0. I think the problem is DHCP. It looks like my TV is getting the gateway etc. of the laptop, in stead of the gateway of my home network. Could this be a part of the solution?

Comment: Could you post the IP address assigned to the TV (by the laptop), IP address of the laptop assigned by the router, and that of the DLMA server? The first three parts should be the same for all. That is, they all should be aaa.bbb.ccc.xxx, where xxx is different for each device. If not, they won't be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: TV: IP 10.42.0.37, Lap: IP 192.168.0.114, DLNA: IP 192.168.0.102

Comment: If you can assign the TV an IP in the 192.168.0.xxx range, then it will see the DNLA server. Sorry, I don't have an answer on how to do this.

Comment: Thanx. I edited my question due to these comments

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly the TV is able to access the Internet but it can't reach the Windows media server?
When I set up a DNLA server in my network (used universal media server) I forgot to open the port on my firewall. My setup slightly differs to yours, however, since my TV is connected directly to the network. It might be worth checking though ;)

Cheers,