# use eth0 and wlan0 at same time

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry pi and I have connected it to my laptop via LAN cable in order to remote it, on the other side I want to use my WiFi to use internet.

When I connect to both of them one of them become disconnected after a while, is there any way to handle this?

If yes can I share my internet over eth0 in order to use internet in Raspberry Pi?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by forwarding packets from wireless card to ethernet.

Do this on your Ubuntu machine

```
 ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1 (or whatever you want)
```

Enable ip_forward by

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Enable forwarding in IPTABLES by

```
 iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Enable NAT mode to connect to internet by

```
 iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

On your RPI set IP to 192.168.1.x and gateway to 192.168.1.x (ubuntu wlan0 ip address)

You might want to invest in a USB WiFi adapter. You can find them on Amazon for as low as $7. Just search Raspberry Pi Wifi

Comment: change my RPI`s eth0 to 192.168.1.x? there is no need to change my laptops eth0?

Answer (score 0):

You can access internet via wlan0 and share it eth0. Don't need to do any changes. Just share eth0 over wlan0.

You can access rpi and surf internet.

Comment: How can I share it? Cause I tried to access internet but I could not

Comment: You can check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port?lq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/169473/sharing-connection-to-other-pcs-via-wired-ethernet