# Share internet connection to distribute ubuntu nodes sitting behind master

Tags: networking, ssh, internet, network-bridge

I'm working on setting up a 20 node distributed system. The data nodes are hp Compaq 6500 pc's running Ubuntu 12.4.5. The master is connected to the internet and I've configured the IP's of the nodes so that communication via ssh can take place between the master and data nodes. However, I would like to share the internet through the master to the 20 data nodes. How should I go about doing this? The master has two network cards. Should I try and bridge the connection or should I go about it a different way? I would also like to have any approach that can be done through the command line. It's much easier to ssh into these machines and set a bash script to run rather than connecting a monitor, keyboard, and mouse 20 different times.

I've tried sharing the internet connection through [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169473/sharing-connection-to-other-pcs-via-wired-ethernet) but it didn't work. If it sounds like I don't know what I'm talking then you've guessed right. This is very new territory for me where I've mainly concentrated on software up until now.

If I haven't explained something well enough or incorrectly, please let me know. Thanks guys