# Connection Sharing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, connection, sharing

I have two PC's, one running Archlinux connected via ethernet to the other Ubuntu 16.04 machine which is connected to a wireless access point.

I followed the steps to share an internet connection in this thread:
[Sharing Connection to other PCs (Via Wired Ethernet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169473/sharing-connection-to-other-pcs-via-wired-ethernet). From my Archlinux pc I am able to ping Ubuntu's ethernet interface as well as Ubuntu's wireless interface, however,  I am unable to ping the wireless access point.

Do I need to configure a bridge between the two interfaces or is it possible the access point is refusing the private IP's i've assigned to my ethernet interfaces?

Comment: Can you add the steps that you performed on your computer for this sharing.  Taking the time to study the configuration you linked to may or may not work.  If it works and your configuration doesn't, we need to see what is different between what works and what you have so that we can point out where your problem is.  I'm familiar with sharing connection, I use the commandline, not the GUI.  From the commandline steps bridging two adapters are part of the configuration.  The GUI in your link may provide the necessary bridge if it's required.

Comment: As soon as I restarted the network service via command line in ubuntu, it was making an identical nic with the static private IP address I assigned to it. All I had to do is delete the new interface and reconfigure the ip on my Archlinux ethernet nic to the same subnet that my ubuntu ethernet nic was automatically assigning via it's connection sharing function. I also had to reconfigure my default gateway as my my ubuntu's ehternet nic ip. I was successfully able to ping google. I appreciate the assistance. Cheers!