# Network manager accidentally purge

Tags: network-manager

I accidentally purge network-manager. .
So Although I try sudo apt install network-manager failed to fetch error occure cause I don't have Internet now.
Pls help me How should I do to get my network-manager and Internet.

Comment: You question should include the complete list of packages that you removed. That list is in your `/var/log/apt/history.log` file. Since you don't have network access, a clear, readable photo of that part of your log will suffice.

Comment: what should i do?how can I go to that file.(I'm beginner of ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your installation medium as a software source, and then install the missing package. A step wise explanation of how you can temporarily set up your installation medium as the software source is provided as an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048260/558158) to another question.

Another technical option would be to try connecting to the network [via the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347618/manually-connecting-to-a-network-via-terminal#348032). Then you could install the missing package. That will only work if you did not remove more essential system packages required for networking.

However, by far the easiest option in case your technical linux skills are still too limited is just a reinstall. While the system is still functional,make sure the backup of your own user data is up to date. Then reinstall - it is easy to do and will take less than an hour.

Answer (score 0):

[![I got the answer view in photo if you aslo have same problem as mine][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Gjc.png**I got the answer.View it in photo if you also have the same probelm as mine.It's really helpful but you must need to know what is your correct linxu's network-manager package.**