# Ubuntu boots to black screen after Update to Ubuntu 18

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have just tried to upgrade my Ubuntu to Ubuntu 18, and at one moment I had to choose if it should install new version of a certain file or keep the old one, and I selected to see the difference. After which, I didn´t know how to close the window and return to upgrade so I pressed  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> which terminated the process completely.

At first I could continue using Linux without any problems, but after I rebooted,  it started making problems.
It shows a black screen where I can move with my mouse, but I can´t do anything else.  So I looked up online what I can do about it, and after trying everything with Booting in recovery mode, I have decided to install a new version of Ubuntu, while keeping the old data on the drive. But it seems that was not the solution either.

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you tried adding `nomodeset` to the end of your grub boot line? https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu Also, could you update question and tell us what video card are you using? Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: hey yes I have tried both nomedeset and nosplash, it show the linux logo as if it is booting up but then just a black screen. I have a NVIDA Geforce 940mx graphic card. I saw that the new instalation created a new partition from which I can boot up normally, but I want to save my data that is why I still try to find a solution for the question

Comment: if you press ctrl+alt+F3 can you get to a command line?

Comment: yes, I access the terminal with ctrl+alt+F1

Comment: awesome... see answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 4):

**You may need to fix a broken install/update.**

If you can get to a command prompt <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and have an internet connection via [ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13993/how-to-connect-to-wired-internet-connection-through-terminal) or [wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line) the fix may be trivial.

From the command prompt:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing
```

Then be sure to install the latest Nvidia drivers from the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Once all is done, reboot and enjoy.

Comment: Hey, I have already tried this. It ended up not allowing me to update the graphics drivers.... it was showing missing dependencies.

Comment: can you edit your original question with the missing deps output?